# Does a 19th Century Approbation Equate to a Modern Day Imprimatur?

Tags: catholicism, imprimatur, approbation

On the 7th electronic page of [*The Precious Blood*](https://ia802601.us.archive.org/21/items/a5807812fabe00uoft/a5807812fabe00uoft.pdf), is found:

[image]

I found no copyright date in this book but Internet Archive estimates it to have been published between 1860 and 1890.

I have noticed that many books such as this one published in the nineteenth century either do not contain an *Imprimatur* or indicate something to the effect (as is the case here): "an Approbation" by a competent ecclesiastical authority---in this instance, the Archbishop of Baltimore (Baltimore being the place where this book was published.)

QUESTION: Would an "Approbation" of this sort constitute what today we refer to as an "Imprimatur"? I ask this, for I have seen the term *imprimatur* used in the late 1800s---but never, as far as I can recall---as late as the early 1800s?

As an aside (not officially part of the above question, might anyone know what "Republished from the Adbance Sheets" means; and, is "Adbance" perhaps, a typo?)

Thank you.

Comment: For your aside, the word is ***Advance,*** with the characteristic shape of the lower-case *v*. An "advance sheet" would appear to be one supplied in advance of publication, probably loose-leaf and maybe even handwritten.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Many thanks for providing  this very useful information.